# The performance at iteration (cache miss)

Tags: c++, caching, vector, iterator

I have found out that the iteration goes through a vector faster when
instead of using a variable (i) to count up `std::vector<T>::iterator` is used.

Thanks to a few comments, here is some additional information: (1)
I use the Visual Studio C++ Compiler; (2) I compiled in release mode and with the optimization -O2 :)

[Image of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVhka.png)

If the variable i is incremented, the iteration takes

5875ms:

```
std::vector<Data> vec(MAX_DATA);
stopWatch.start();
for (unsigned i = 0U; i < MAX_DATA; ++i) {
    vec[i].x = 0;
    vec[i].y = 0;
}
stopWatch.stop();
stopWatch.printSpanAsMs("The data are stored in memory next to each other");
```

or 5723ms:

```
std::vector<Data*> vec2;
for (unsigned i = 0U; i < MAX_DATA; ++i)
    vec2.push_back(new Data());

stopWatch.start();
for (unsigned i = 0U; i < MAX_DATA; ++i) {
    vec2[i]->x = 0;
    vec2[i]->y = 0;
}
stopWatch.stop();
stopWatch.printSpanAsMs("The data is in memory at a random position");
```

If `std::vector<Data>::Iterator` is used to iterate, the iteration will take

29ms:

```
std::vector<Data> vec(MAX_DATA);

stopWatch.start();
for (auto& it : vec) {
    it.x = 0;
    it.y = 0;
}
stopWatch.stop();
stopWatch.printSpanAsMs("The data are stored in memory next to each other");
```

or 110ms:

```
std::vector<Data*> vec2;
for (unsigned i = 0U; i < MAX_DATA; ++i)
    vec2.push_back(new Data());

stopWatch.start();
for (auto& it : vec2) {
    it->x = 0;
    it->y = 0;
}
stopWatch.stop();
stopWatch.printSpanAsMs("The data is in memory at a random position");
```

Why is the other iteration so much faster?

I'm wondering that the iteration with the variable i at which the data is at different positions in the memory is as fast as the iteration with the variable i, where data is juxtaposed in the memory.
The fact that the data is next to each other in the memory should reduce cache misses and that works with the iteration with `std::vector<Data>::Iterator`, why not with the other one?
Or do I dare and the distance of 29 to 110ms is not the cache misses in debt?

The entire program looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class StopWatch
{
public:
    void start() {
        this->t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }

    void stop() {
        this->t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        this->diff = t2 - t1;
    }

    void printSpanAsMs(std::string startText = "time span") {
        long diffAsMs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
        (diff).count();
        std::cout << startText << ": " << diffAsMs << "ms" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1, t2;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration   diff;
} stopWatch;

struct Data {
    int x, y;
};

const unsigned long MAX_DATA = 20000000;

void test1()
{
    std::cout << "1. Test \n Use i to iterate through the vector" << 
    std::endl;

    std::vector<Data> vec(MAX_DATA);
    stopWatch.start();
    for (unsigned i = 0U; i < MAX_DATA; ++i) {
        vec[i].x = 0;
        vec[i].y = 0;
    }
    stopWatch.stop();
    stopWatch.printSpanAsMs("The data are stored in memory next to each 
    other");

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    std::vector<Data*> vec2;
    for (unsigned i = 0U; i < MAX_DATA; ++i)
        vec2.push_back(new Data());

    stopWatch.start();
    for (unsigned i = 0U; i < MAX_DATA; ++i) {
        vec2[i]->x = 0;
        vec2[i]->y = 0;
    }
    stopWatch.stop();
    stopWatch.printSpanAsMs("The data is in memory at a random position");

    for (unsigned i = 0U; i < MAX_DATA; ++i) {
        delete vec2[i];
        vec2[i] = nullptr;
    }
}

void test2()
{
    std::cout << "2. Test \n Use std::vector<T>::iteraror to iterate through 
    the vector" << std::endl;

    std::vector<Data> vec(MAX_DATA);

    stopWatch.start();
    for (auto& it : vec) {
        it.x = 0;
        it.y = 0;
    }
    stopWatch.stop();
    stopWatch.printSpanAsMs("The data are stored in memory next to each 
    other");

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    std::vector<Data*> vec2;
    for (unsigned i = 0U; i < MAX_DATA; ++i)
        vec2.push_back(new Data());

    stopWatch.start();
    for (auto& it : vec2) {
        it->x = 0;
        it->y = 0;
    }
    stopWatch.stop();
    stopWatch.printSpanAsMs("The data is in memory at a random position");

    for (auto& it : vec2) {
        delete it;
        it = nullptr;
    }
}

int main()
{
    test1();
    test2();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? What flags are you using?

Comment: I use Visual Studio and std::chrono::high_resolution_clock.

Comment: what optimization level? try `-O2` at least

Comment: @SOUser: visual studio is not a compiler. You didn't mention whether you have optimizations enabled. Without optimizations your benchmarks are meaningless.

Comment: @SOUser Did you compile in release mode, with full optimizations enabled? Questioning the performance of unoptimized code is pointless.

Comment: I compiled in release mode.
Which optimizations? What should I activate exactly?

Comment: Sigh. Can people finally stop needlessly littering their programs with unsigned integer types? And if you think you *must* go unsigned (you don't), at least pick the right one. https://godbolt.org/g/Qf4zgj

Comment: Thank you. Have learned something again, O2 was coincidentally already set for me.

Comment: Unsigned should be wrong? I only use numbers over 0, so I used unsigned. What's wrong with it?

Comment: In this case, it's about the only type that inhibits the compiler from optimizing the loop into a call to `memset` as it must "correctly" wrap around if the numbers get too big. See the generated assembly in the link above. Generally, I suggest you use `int` unless that's potentially too small and `int64_t` otherwise; for everything but bit-magic. For that use unsigned of whatever fixed size you need. I know that's controversial, but I am not alone on this: 
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything 9:50, 42:40, 1:02:50

Comment: "it must "correctly" wrap around if the numbers get too big" I see your point, but int and unsigned are the same size. Yes, I'll check it out right away.

Comment: True, but overflowing signed types like `int` invokes UB and the optimizer can and does assume that doesn't happen. Of course that means you have a bug if you overflow your index, signed or not, so make sure you pick an appropriate type. As I said, `int64_t` if in doubt.

Comment: Of course. Wait...

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Your `auto` is a `int`... so it is not the right `unsigned` one.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah right, oops. Thanks for the correction. `std::size_t` does the trick, too. The second part is good to note, yet I still stand by my opinion that a signed type is more appropriate for indices.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: As you said, it is controversial. (I would be for unsigned type, as negative indexes doesn't make sense ;-) ).

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't really buy this argument. True, negative indices don't make sense, but when was an accidental wrap-around ever less of a bug than an accidentally negative index? At least the latter is trivial to `assert` for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the other iteration so much faster?

The reason is that MSVC 2017 cannot optimize it properly.

In the first case it completely fails to optimize the loop:

```
for (unsigned i = 0U; i < MAX_DATA; ++i) {
    vec[i].x = 0;
    vec[i].y = 0;
}
```

Generated code ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/g/6dSez1)):

```
        xor      r9d, r9d
        mov      eax, r9d
$LL4@test1:
        mov      rdx, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        lea      rax, QWORD PTR [rax+16]
        mov      DWORD PTR [rax+rdx-16], r9d
        mov      rdx, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        mov      DWORD PTR [rax+rdx-12], r9d
        mov      rdx, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        mov      DWORD PTR [rax+rdx-8], r9d
        mov      rdx, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        mov      DWORD PTR [rax+rdx-4], r9d
        sub      r8, 1
        jne      SHORT $LL4@test1
```

Replacing `unsigned i` with `size_t i` or hoisting indexed access into a reference doesn't help ([demo](https://godbolt.org/g/2KvwK1)).

The only thing that helps is using an iterator like you have already found out:

```
for (auto& it : vec) {
    it.x = 0;
    it.y = 0;
}
```

Generated code ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/g/WCBS5W)):

```
        xor      ecx, ecx
        npad     2
$LL4@test2:
        mov      QWORD PTR [rax], rcx
        add      rax, 8
        cmp      rax, rdx
        jne      SHORT $LL4@test2
```

clang just calls `memset` in both cases.

The moral of the story: *look* at the generated code if you care about performance. Report issues to the vendor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can not assembler, but the code looks a lot smaller. "If you replace unsigned i with size_t i the code looks better" Yes, it looks better, but it does not change anything in terms of performance.

Comment: Bottom line is MSVC generates inefficient code when not using an iterator. You can't "fix" it, only Microsoft can (maybe in the next version).